# In Juni5, how to run multiple test suites

Tags: java, junit5

I created multiple test suites for different categories (each category has its own test suite).
I want to create a super test suite that all the other test suites will be executed after the super test suite is executed (it contains a generic setup for the all test suites).

Example:

Test1 in the first test suite:

```java
@ExtendWith(TestSuiteX.class)
public class Test1SuiteX {

    @Test
    public void Test1SuiteX() {
        System.out.println("Inside Test1Suite1");
    }
}
```

Test2 in the second test suite:

```java
@ExtendWith(TestSuiteY.class)
public class Test2SuiteY {

    @Test
    public void Test2SuiteY() {
        System.out.println("Inside Test1Suite1");
    }
}
```

TestSuiteX:

```java
@Suite
@SelectPackages({"tests packages ..."})
public class TestSuiteX implements BeforeAllCallback, ExtensionContext.Store.CloseableResource {

    private static boolean started = false;

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) {
        if (!started) {
            started = true;
            System.out.println("TestSuiteX setting up");
            context.getRoot().getStore(GLOBAL).put("any unique name", this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("TestSuiteX tearing down");
    }

}
```

TestSuiteY:

```java
@Suite
@SelectPackages({"tests packages ..."})
public class TestSuiteY implements BeforeAllCallback, ExtensionContext.Store.CloseableResource {

    private static boolean started = false;

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) {
        if (!started) {
            started = true;
            System.out.println("TestSuiteY setting up");
            context.getRoot().getStore(GLOBAL).put("any unique name", this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("TestSuiteY tearing down");
    }

}
```

The above is working fine, I want to introduce a new test suite that make me able to run some code before executing the tests inside TestSuiteX and TestSuiteY (and any other existing test suites).

Example:

```java
@Suite
@SelectPackages({"tests packages ..."})
public class MainSuite implements BeforeAllCallback, ExtensionContext.Store.CloseableResource {

    Method1(): // WANT THIS TO RUN IN THE BEGINNING (before the beforeAll() methods in TestSuiteX and TestSuiteY)

    Method2(): // WANT THIS TO RUN IN THE END (after the close() methods in TestSuiteX and TestSuiteY)

}
```

Is that possible in JUni5?